# Flutter push custom widget outside of a layout

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a custom widget (this is the layout implementation)

```
CustomPaint(
  size: Size(double.infinity, double.infinity),
  painter: OvalPainter(),
)
```

And this is a child of a `Container`. I now want this widget to be pushed out of it for about 30%. Here's a visualization

[image: Desired result]

I tried clipping it and then using some margin but it wouldn't work. In Android Studio, I simply put `android:layout_marginBottom="-50dp"` to my custom view, but negative values to a `Padding` throws an error

> I/flutter ( 6808): 'package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart': Failed assertion: line 107 pos 15:
>
> I/flutter ( 6808): 'padding.isNonNegative': is not true.

EDIT: The solution is as following

```
return ClipRect(
  clipper: myClipper(), //optional
  child: OverflowBox(
    minHeight: ITEM_HEIGHT * 1.5,
    maxHeight: ITEM_HEIGHT * 2,
    child: CustomPaint(
      size: Size(double.infinity, ITEM_HEIGHT * 1.5),
      painter: OvalPainter()
    ),
  ),
);
```

So I make the widget larger than the space and then clip it

Comment: Can you share OvalPainter class and current screenshot ?

Comment: The real class is something else, I just illustrated it here with an oval so make it clear what I want visible.

Comment: if you want to clip it use one of `Canvas.clip*()` method

Comment: in the paint method? Well, I don't want 70% of an oval every time, When I click the container, I want to open a new page showing the entire oval. In this case, the container I'm talking about is a list item so I'm showing multiple ovals below each other but I dont show them entirely to save space

Comment: pass a valid height, not infinity, and you will be able to clip the content drawn in your `CustomPainter`

Comment: and? did passing the valid height help?

Comment: Yes, I made the widget larger than its parent and then clipped it (see edit)

Comment: i mean you can use `Canvas.clip*()` methods, not `ClipRect` widget

Answer (score 1):

I made something like this with `CustomClipper`, Is that what u want ?

[image]

This is the `OvalClipper` class with `CustomClipper`

```
class OvalClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  static const double PAD = 20;

  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = Path();

    path.addOval(
      Rect.fromCenter(
        center: Offset(size.width / 2, size.height * 0.7),
        width: size.width - 2 * PAD,
        height: size.height,
      ),
    );

    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => true;
}
```

And how can we use it

```
Container(
  width: 200,
  height: 200,
  color: Colors.green,
  child: ClipPath(
    clipper: OvalClipper(),
    child: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
    ),
)
```

Comment: Something like that yes but the top of the oval should still reach the top of the container. (i.e. the oval is bigger than the container but it's partly outside of it)